# which font to use for consistent online experience?

Tags: css, fonts

Which is one (or more) font that is readily available for browsers on:

- Android
- iOS
- Windows
- Linux
- OSX

And that look very similar on every platform?

Comment: That was a fast edit! thanks for the much improved title.

Comment: So, should i answer this with 'none' and close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say go with Arial.

One of the easiest to read and is very consistent across all browsers.

You might be interested in this:

http://www.upsdell.com/BrowserNews/res_fonts.htm#a01

Comment: This is an interesting table, but lists arial and helvetica as available on linux, also has some other misses on the default windows fonts. And there's no font that is green on all columns :(

Comment: Yes, @gcb.  I think there are no sure things.  `Arial` with a `sans-serif` fall back is always the best, I think.

Answer (score 2):

That's an issue [Core Web Fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web) are supposed to address but I think Microsoft has changed licensing terms so you can't quite count on same core web font being on Linux even thought the substitutes will be very, very close.

The best option is to embed any of the [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace%3aselect) in your pages for everything looking identical. If that's not a option, Helvetica on a mac, Arial on a Win, and default sans-serif on Linux will be close enough that very few users could tell them apart.

Comment: interesting, using "font-family:sans-serif" under ubuntu gives me a font that looks like arial on windows and helvetica on mac. But as soon as i use "font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif" under chrome it will use one font that does not look like neither! it's a font I can't identify... looks like arial, but has a top serif on the uppercase J. it's sans-serif other than just a few letters. such as f, J, i, I, l.